# Adding transitions to hide/show list items

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

Basically, I have a filtered list that's using jquery to hide/show the correct elements inside a large UL.

Currently, I'm just using `display:none` and `display:block`. Since you can't put transitions on these elements I am wondering the best way to go about this.

I cant use opacity:0; and visibility:0 because it leaves large gaps within the ul where the correct li should be hidden. Display block/none was working perfectly but I want to add a transition so when the item is clicked the correct li's fade in and the ones that should be hidden fade out.

```
<div class="jobs-filter">
  <span>Filter by:</span>
  <ul>
      <li class="jobs-list"><a class="jobs filter item europe" href="#">Europe</a></li> 
      <li class="jobs-list"><a class="jobs filter item north-america" href="#">North America</a></li>   
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="listing">
                <ul>
                    <li class="europe">
                        <a target="_blank" href="#">
                            <div class="left">
                                <span class="title">Europe Test</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="right"> 
                                <span class="job-arrow"></span>
                            </div>
                        </a> 
                    </li>
        <li class="north-america">
                        <a target="_blank" href="#">
                            <div class="left">
                                <span class="title">NA Test</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="right"> 
                                <span class="job-arrow"></span>
                            </div>
                        </a> 
                    </li>
        <li class="europe">
                        <a target="_blank" href="#">
                            <div class="left">
                                <span class="title">Europe Test</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="right"> 
                                <span class="job-arrow"></span>
                            </div>
                        </a> 
                    </li>
        <li class="north-america">
                        <a target="_blank" href="#">
                            <div class="left">
                                <span class="title">NA Test</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="right"> 
                                <span class="job-arrow"></span>
                            </div>
                        </a> 
                    </li>
        <li class="europe">
                        <a target="_blank" href="#">
                            <div class="left">
                                <span class="title">Europe Test</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="right"> 
                                <span class="job-arrow"></span>
                            </div>
                        </a> 
                    </li>
        <li class="north-america">
                        <a target="_blank" href="#">
                            <div class="left">
                                <span class="title">NA Test</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="right"> 
                                <span class="job-arrow"></span>
                            </div>
                        </a> 
                    </li>
         <li class="europe">
                        <a target="_blank" href="#">
                            <div class="left">
                                <span class="title">Europe Test</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="right"> 
                                <span class="job-arrow"></span>
                            </div>
                        </a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Does anyone know the best way to go about this?

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/Davabo/pen/wPaJKV/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [jQuery slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) (or separately jquery slideUp and jquery slideDown). As you can see i give a data-nation to each element of the filter above the list and added a class with the same text to each element of the list. So when i click on the filters, it shows the elements with the class equal to the data-nation filter. Let me know if you need further help. :)

```js
$('.nation-trigger').click(function (e){
  e.preventDefault()
  var nation = $(this).data('nation')
  $('.nation-element.active').slideUp().removeClass('active')
  $('.nation-element.' + nation).slideDown().addClass('active')
})
```

```css
.nation-element{
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jobs-filter">
  <span>Filter by:</span>
  <ul>
    <li class="jobs-list">
      <a data-nation="europe" class="nation-trigger" href="#">
      Europe
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="jobs-list">
      <a data-nation="north-america" class="nation-trigger" href="#">
      North America
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="listing">
  <ul>
    <li class="europe nation-element">
      <a target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="left">
          <span class="title">Europe Test</span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <span class="job-arrow"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="north-america nation-element">
      <a target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="left">
          <span class="title">NA Test</span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <span class="job-arrow"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="europe nation-element">
      <a target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="left">
          <span class="title">Europe Test</span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <span class="job-arrow"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="north-america nation-element">
      <a target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="left">
          <span class="title">NA Test</span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <span class="job-arrow"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="europe nation-element">
      <a target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="left">
          <span class="title">Europe Test</span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <span class="job-arrow"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="north-america nation-element">
      <a target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="left">
          <span class="title">NA Test</span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <span class="job-arrow"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="europe nation-element">
      <a target="_blank" href="#">
        <div class="left">
          <span class="title">Europe Test</span>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <span class="job-arrow"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```